# what is the difference between GDIFF and BSDIFF apart from the reduced patch size

Tags: compression, delta

i read the thesis on how executable files change and i'm totally confused between the concepts of GDIFF and BSDIFF . can anyone explain me how it works?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GDIFF and BSDIFF algorithm needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184826/gdiff-and-bsdiff-algorithm-needed)

Comment: i wasn't getting any answers for it , may be i need to post in an another for m expressing the exact needs